# Bug in input text layout or my mistake?

Tags: android, android-edittext

when the user input correct value in first attempt then its fine but when the user give correct input after the error is set in the [edittext](/questions/tagged/edittext)
 with [textinputlayout](/questions/tagged/textinputlayout) then the whole background of editText goes black and while error is set background goes Red,and while in focus and input type is correct background goes **colorAccent**(default color name in studio)

**xml**

```xml
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/input_layout_email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/reservation_email_edit_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/reservation_edit_text_drawable"
                android:hint="Email"
                android:inputType="textWebEmailAddress"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

**code**

```java
 private boolean validateEmail() {

    String email = etEmail.getText().toString().trim();

    if (email.isEmpty() || !isValidEmail(email)) {
        ipEmail.setError("Enter valid email address");

        return false;
    } else {
        ipEmail.setErrorEnabled(false);
    }

    return true;
}
```

**reservation_edit_text_drawable.xml**

```java
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_focused="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/red_border" />

<item android:drawable="@drawable/normal_border" />

</selector>
```

**red_border.xml**

```java
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >
<padding android:top="5dp"/>
<stroke android:width="1dp"
    android:color="#CC1F26" />
<size  android:height="48dp"/>
</shape>
```

**normal_border.xml**

```java
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >
<stroke android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@color/disabled_color" />
<size android:height="48dp"
    />
</shape>
```

**Base App Theme default**

```java
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

**ScreenShot**

[image: SCREENSHOT OF MY PROBLEM]

Comment: If possible, please share the code of drawable/reservation_edit_text_drawable and your base app theme from styles.xml

Comment: at first set `if (email.isEmpty() && !isValidEmail(email))`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya no the if condition is fine, because the error needs to be displayed when either the field is empty or the entered characters doesn't correspond to a standard email format.

Comment: @AdityaNaik code of drawable is updated....have a look

Comment: @themrhornet sorry, buddy. Tried out various attributes, but cannot control the background color of EditText. Try raising it as a Design Library issue at http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/ . Google engineers should know exactly which attribute you need to set.

Comment: @themrhornet btw, the bug is fixed if you remove `android:background="@drawable/reservation_edit_text_drawable"` from EditText and set it to TextInputLayout instead. But I don't think that's what you want.

Comment: yeah that's not what i want...i appreciate your effort to solve my problem.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem while using custom xml as edittext background.
Removing it worked for me.
Try removing the line `android:background="@drawable/reservation_edit_text_drawable"`

Answer (score 1):

There are some bug with `TextInputLayout`, which are been already posted .

please refer these links

- TextInputLayout error visibility bug ([link](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=191876))
- TextInputLayout not showing hint until focused([link](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=175228))
- TextInputLayout setError() will not show an error after it is cleared([link](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=190355))

Comment: Yes, TIL is buggy atm, but this bug appears to be local to his code.

Comment: i would say there are many more bug in TextInputLayout  than these may be one of local code.

Comment: I know, TIL is buggy when it is accompanied with error methods. I have reported one myself (https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=197157), but I think his bug is in the background drawable he has set fot the editText. He should either remove it, or pass a style with custom colors for `colorControlNormal` and `colorControlActivated`.

Comment: if you know than help @themrhornet

Comment: Yes, I have requested him to share the code for base theme and the drawable file. Awaiting his response.

Comment: is this answer helped ?@themrhornet

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting Error why don't you use Toast Message. I faced the same problem so I tried with Toast Message. For this try some thing like below

-> When User clicks on Second Field, then check first Edit Text is filled properly or not . If Yes then Only User can Enter Data in Second field other wise not.